# What do you use to loadbalance IPv6 services?

Tags: linux, networking, load-balancing, ipv6

the current Linux software environment for IPv6 load balancing looks a bit grim.

[IPVS](http://kb.linuxvirtualserver.org/wiki/IPv6_load_balancing) has rudimentary support for IPv6 but it's far from complete. NAT for IPv6 seems to be a no-go. Are there any other projects which aim for this goal? Does the IPv6 support in other OS look better? Are there any commercial products which have been successfully used in production environments with non-trivial load patterns?

Or is it just that the time for IPv6 hasn't come... yet? ;)

best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say that NAT for IPv6 is a no-go?  A Many to One NAT is silly, but there is no reason to avoid One to many (load balancing) or Many to Many translations.

There are [several](http://www.ch.ipv6tf.org/downloads/files/Christoph_Schneeberger_GSEC.pdf) [discussions](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/firewalls/building_an_ipv6_firewall_with_openbsd_807?show=807.php&cat=firewalls) of using OpenBSD and PF to make IPv6 firewalls.  You won't get ASIC speeds, but such things are fine for borders and probably wouldn't do too badly in a core.

Answer (score 0):

Test thoroughly, IPv6 is not quite mainstream enough.

Have a look at Cisco's latest ACE core modules, not the stand-alone units.

Answer (score 0):

nginx is an option if you only need to load balance http/https.